# How to replace asterisk symbols (*) with bold tags to denote important words and phrases?

Tags: find-and-replace, text-editing

I have a document of nearly 20K lines. Many (but not all) of the lines use asterisk symbols to denote important words and phrases.

Example:

```
What kind of *vegetable* is it?
You are *best?!*
I hope I am not late.
All *the "good"* shows are *no longer* broadcasting.
```

I would like to replace the asterisk symbols with html bold tags. E.g. so it looks like this:

```
What kind of <b>vegetable</b> is it?
You are <b>best?!</b>  
I hope I am not late.
All <b>the "good"</b> shows are <b>no longer</b> broadcasting.
```

What's the best way of doing this?
I can't just do a find and replace, because it won’t insert the appropriate closing `</b>` tag when required.

My document is currently in a spreadsheet but I can import it into any other format, so long as it can be returned to the spreadsheet.

My environment:
I am using Apple Numbers on Mac OSX. But I am happy to install another application. I also have Windows on Virtual Box but would prefer to avoid using that if possible.

### update

One more question: If I wanted to create a new column that had just words in asterisk symbols prefixed with the word "Emphasize"" and nothing else, would that be possible with plugin? If so, how?

Example:

- What kind of *vegetable* is it?
  becomes
  Emphasize: vegetable
- All *the "good"* shows are *no longer* broadcasting.
  becomes
  Emphasize: the good, Emphasize: no longer.

Comment: Do you use Windows or Linux? Excel, OpenOffice, LibreOffice, something else? Please [edit] your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Excel you can use free [RegEx Find Replace add-in](http://www.codedawn.com/excel-add-ins.php) to perform a replace using regular expressions:

[image]

*I'm not affiliated with that add-in in any way, just use it as I find it useful.*

---

### Update

The expression should work also in other tools with regex support (https://regex101.com/r/928oKB/1)

If your entries may contain other characters too, then just change "Find what" expression to:
`\*([^*]+)\*`
It'll capture everything between two `*`

(you can test it [here](https://regex101.com/r/F3FQYb/1))

### Update:

Yes, you can add "Emphasize" too, however that is easier with a helper column.

- Formula for the helper column:
  `=RegExReplace(A1,"[^*]*\*([^*]+)\*[^*]*",", Emphasize: $1")`
- Formula for the result:
  `=RIGHT(B1,LEN(B1)-2)`

[image]

Comment: Will that regex command in your screenshot work in any Regex editor or is it for excel only. Thanks!

Comment: But it doesn't correctly find a span which contains e.g. punctuation; the regex in the screen shot only covers alphabetics and spaces.

Comment: @MátéJuhász that might be a problem for me as some of my spans do have punctuation. (I better update my question with this!)

Comment: @MátéJuhász Thanks, I got the plugin working and your expression works perfectly. One more question: If I wanted to create a new column that had just words in asterisk symbols prefixed with the word "Emphasize"" and nothing else, would that be possible with plugin. If so, how. Example: `What kind of *vegetable* is it?` becomes `Emphasize: vegetable` in the new column. `All *the "good"* shows are *no longer* broadcasting.` becomes `Emphasize: the good, Emphasize: no longer`. Thanks for any help you can offer.